# Subfunctor of representable is continuous

Tags: ct.category-theory

Given an object $A$ in a category $\mathcal{C}$, the functor $Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(A,-)$ is tautologically continuous i.e. limit-preserving. Let $F$ be a subfunctor of $Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(A,-)$, is $F$ in general continuous? We might assume $F$ is fully-faithful if necessary.

Comment: Take $\mathcal C$ a meet-semilattice. Not every sub-upper-set of a principal filter is a filter.

Comment: It might be actually true for fully faithful $F$, since there are hardly any. What would be your example of a fully faithful subfunctor of a representable functor?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I do have an example for the fully faithful $F$ but it seems not easy to describe in a few lines... Do you have a proof / reference  that such $F$ is necessarily continuous? Thanks!